# How do I change the value of variable in C just by changing the parameter

Tags: c, cs50

I want to be able to have the variables constantly change. 
Right now they rely on a parameter but when I change that parameter nothing changes,
Below is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)

{
    int n;

    do
    {
        printf ("Please put in a positive number no larger than 24.");
        n = GetInt();
    }
    while (n < 0 || n > 23);

    int rownumber = 0;
    int numberofhashes = rownumber + 2;
    int numberofspaces = rownumber + 1 - numberofhashes;

    while (rownumber < n)
    {
        printf ("rownumber is %d", rownumber);
        printf ("hashes # is %d", numberofhashes);
        printf ("numerofspaces is %d", numberofspaces);
        while (numberofspaces > 0)
        {
            printf ("passed");
            printf (" ");
            numberofspaces = numberofspaces - 1;
        }
        while (numberofhashes > 0)
        {
            printf ("passed");
            printf ("#");
            numberofhashes = numberofhashes - 1;
        }
        rownumber = rownumber + 1;
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

(If you're wondering, project from CS 50, I can't post to those forums for some reason)

I set numberofhashes and numberofspaces to be reliant on the row number, but apparently they don't change then I change the row number. Please help!

EDIT: Guys, thanks for the response, I was able to fix it, EXCEPT, now it's printing the pyramid all wrong. It's printing

```
##
###
####
#####
```

instead of

```
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
```

like it's supposed to.

So, here's the code again. Also, I'm a newbie so please tell me if this type of follow up questions are not preferred.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)

{
    int n;

    do
    {
        printf ("Please put in a positive number no larger than 24.");
        n = GetInt();
    }
    while (n < 0 || n > 23);

    int rownumber = 0;
    int numberofhashes = rownumber + 2;
    int numberofspaces = rownumber + 1 - numberofhashes;

    while (rownumber < n)
    {
        numberofhashes = rownumber + 2;
        numberofspaces = rownumber + 1 - numberofhashes;
        while (numberofspaces > 0)
        {
            printf (" ");
            numberofspaces = numberofspaces - 1;
        }
        while (numberofhashes > 0)
        {
            printf ("#");
            numberofhashes = numberofhashes - 1;
        }
        rownumber = rownumber + 1;
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
```

Edit: Problem solved.

Comment: What does not happen when you change what ?

Comment: in the `main()` function, a message tells the user to enter a positive integer, no greater than 24.   Yet the `do...while()` statement only allows values in the range 0...23  I.E. is rejects 24.

Comment: regarding these statements: `int rownumber = 0;
    int numberofhashes = rownumber + 2;
    int numberofspaces = rownumber + 1 - numberofhashes;`,  the result is `rownumber` is 0, `numberofhashes` is 2, `numberofspaces` is -1.  are those the results you actually want?

Comment: strongly suggest each of the `format strings` for the `printf()` function calls be terminated with a '\n' so 1) the text is immediately output 2) the different parts of the text be output on different lines. for readability

Comment: during the first two iterations of tis loop: `while (rownumber < n)` remember, `numberofspaces` starts as -1, so this loop: `while (numberofspaces > 0)` is never entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question appears to be based on a fundamental misunderstanding of what your code is doing. You seem to believe that the line

```
int numberofhashes = rownumber + 2;
```

should create some kind of continual 'dependency' of some kind; that is to say, that each time `rownumber` changes, the value of number `numberofhashes` should change along with it.

This is not how C works; what this statement does is to set the value of `numberofhashes` to be equal to the value of `rownumber + 2` *at that moment in time only*.

If you want numberofhashes to continually change to rownumber + 2, then you will need to include the statement

```
numberofhashes = rownumber + 2;
```

Somewhere *inside* the loop. That way, each time the loop executes, your statement is reevaluated and the value of `numberofhashes` is updated.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
int numberofhashes = rownumber + 2;
int numberofspaces = rownumber + 1 - numberofhashes;
```

that means:

```
numberofspaces = rownumber + 1 - (rownumber + 2) = rownumber + 1 - rownumber - 2 = -1
```

`numberofspaces` will be always negative.
How can you enter into the while?

```
 while (numberofspaces > 0)
```

I think you have some logical problem in your code that you should fix.